# How do I report a site that is misusing the Ubuntu logo and trademark?

Tags: canonical, logo

Ok while browsing for an answer to a problem mentioned here at askubuntu I found this site "Ubuntu Addict" which looks like a google advert driver. Is there a place I can report something like that if I see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you think it's against [the trademark policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy), report it to Canonical through [this page](https://forms.canonical.com/trademarkviolation/).

Their legal team will be able to assess and action any issue they have with it.

Comment: Coincidentally, it probably is breach of the trademark's license but you could probably level that against other money-earning sites  (even this one) though they might have permission. The legal team will know. They're the only people that can bring action.

Comment: I assume adding the site to WOT wouldn't harm either

Comment: @Jorge thanks for the extra link straight to the report-trademark-violation form. Answered this from my phone, outside so I was a little more limited in my access to Google at the time! @Allen Web of Trust? You mean reporting the site on there as a bad one? Might be an idea but it should be fairly obvious that it's just a feed aggregating nonsense-site. Hopefully Canonical can just DMCA them for stealing the site theme though (copyright infringement - though I'm not sure on the license). Their site is hosted in the US, so that should be viable.